# How to create partial dependence plots for multinomial gbm?

Tags: r, plot, partial, multinomial, gbm

I am trying to create partial dependence plots for my multinomial gbm predictions but I haven't been able to figure out how to produce the correct plots, the ones that I am getting have a single line instead of a line for every level of my response variable (in my case are 3 different species names). I have seen several examples but they require objects created with other packages (not gbm objects) and most of the examples don't include multinomial variables.

#### gbm fit

```
gbm.fit.final<-readRDS(file = "gbm_fit_final1_organism.rds")
```

#### getting table with variable importance

```
summary.gbm<-summary(
  gbm.fit.final, 
  cBars = 10,
  method = relative.influence, 
  las = 2)
```

The table looks like this:

```
          var   rel.inf
     MA0356.1 22.641689
     MA1071.1 21.707397
     MA0311.1 16.010605
     MA0210.1  7.249431
     MA0271.1  4.958186
```

I used the following code to generate the partial dependence plot for the most important predictor variable:

```
gbm.fit.final %>%
  partial(pred.var = "MA0356.1", n.trees = gbm.fit.final$n.trees, grid.resolution = 100, prob=T) %>%
  autoplot(rug = TRUE, train = motifs_train.100) +
  scale_y_continuous()
```

motifs_train.100 is the training data that I used to create the gbm fit (gbm.fit.final), I am not sure if it is necessary to add the training data.

I got the following plot:

[plot with single line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6MDG.png)

I would like to get a plot like this one (I think I need to get marginal probabilities):

[plot with a line for each level of response variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yJs1.png)

I am very new to gbm package. I don't know if there is an argument of the function partial that I am omitting, or if there is a better function to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what stops you from getting the predictions for all your variables, and *then* plotting everything ?

Comment: Nothing, I want the plots for the most important variables, I could make plots for all of them (they are 100) but still I don't know how to plot the partial dependence including the classes of the response variables. This is just an example of what I want to to.

Comment: I mean, the predictor variables are not the issue, I want to include the response variable (species)